# Install software from tar file

Tags: make, gnuplot

So, I was trying to instal gnuplot 5.2.2 from the source files.  I use ubuntu 16.04 LTS, here's what I did: I unpacked the tar file and used the following commands in the source directory:

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Each one at a time... But it seems that no gnuplot is installed in this process, here are the "log" files generated by each command: [./configure](https://paste.ubuntu.com/26455838/), [make](https://paste.ubuntu.com/26455873/) & [make install](https://paste.ubuntu.com/26455851/). Thanks in advance...

Comment: You should direct this question to the author of the software [gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/)

Comment: most 'from source' contain a README (name may vary) with instructions, follow the instructions that came from it, or the website it came from.  The `configure` script checks your system for requirements, it didn't produce errors did it (which mean following steps will likely fail, and provide clues as to what is missing from your system etc)

Answer (score 1):

First of all [`gnuplot` is packaged](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&exact=1&searchon=names&keywords=gnuplot).

If you really want to compile it read below:

Do not forget to enable Source code repositories from *Software & Updates* aka `software-properties-gtk` (*Ubuntu Software* tab, check *Source Code* here).

Second for successful compilation you should install its build-dependencies with:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep gnuplot
```

Then you could clone gnuplot repository from Debian (Ubuntu upstream):

```
git clone git://anonscm.debian.org/debian-science/packages/gnuplot.git
```

And proceed as you already done. Last step may be [`checkinstall`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingSoftware#Installing_the_Package) instead of `make install`.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply! I got errors in the "git clone" part, but I managed to install gnuplot 5.0 with "sudo apt-get install gnuplot-qt". Thanks again!